# How can I append data from html to array in views from a button?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to build a website that generates a power hour style video from a list of music videos that the user selects by searching through the youtube api. I'm having trouble figuring out how to append selected videos to a list (addedVideos) in view.py from a button (add) in my html. I need to append each added video to a list so I can display them and loop through them in an embedded youtube player. This is my first django project so I don't have a good understanding of what the potential problems could be. index.html and views.py below:

views.py

```
import requests

from isodate import parse_duration

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    addedVideos = []
    videos = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
        video_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'

        search_params = {
            'part' : 'snippet',
            'q' : request.POST['search'],
            'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY,
            'maxResults' : 3,
            'type' : 'video'
        }
        #print(request.POST['submit'])
        r = requests.get(search_url, params=search_params)
        #print(r)

        results = r.json()['items']

        #print(results)

        video_ids = []
        for result in results:
            video_ids.append(result['id']['videoId'])

        if request.POST['submit'] == 'lucky':
            return redirect(f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={ video_ids[0] }')

        video_params = {
            'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY,
            'part' : 'snippet,contentDetails',
            'id' : ','.join(video_ids),
            'maxResults' : 3
        }

        r = requests.get(video_url, params=video_params)

        results = r.json()['items']

        
        for result in results:
            video_data = {
                'title' : result['snippet']['title'],
                'id' : result['id'],
                'url' : f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={ result["id"] }',
                'duration' : int(parse_duration(result['contentDetails']['duration']).total_seconds() // 60),
                'thumbnail' : result['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url']
            }
            videos.append(video_data)

        if request.POST['add'] == 'addValue':
            print("add clicked")

    context = {
        'videos' : videos,
        'addedVideos': addedVideos
    }
    
    return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Search YouTube</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'search/album.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<main role="main">

  <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Build Your Power Hour</h1>
      <p class="lead text-muted">Select music videos to add to your power hour</p>
      <form method="POST">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" aria-label="Username">
      </div>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-primary my-2">YouTube Search</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="lucky" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
      </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        {% for video in videos %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" src="{{ video.thumbnail }}" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"></img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{ video.title }}</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <form method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" name="add" value="addValue" id='{{ video }}' class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Add</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ video.duration }} mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this as is gives a MultiValueDictKeyError at 'q' : request.POST['search'],

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to  change request.POST['search'] to request.POST.get('search', '')

Answer (score 1):

You should put `/` in front of `search/index.html` instead of `search/index.html`.

And you don't have to have the `https://` you can just put `//` instead.